# Alinhamento superior com uma elemento centralizado

Tags: css

Tenho uma `div` e preciso colocar um texto a esquerda, outro a direita, e um `icon` centralizado, todos alinhados por cima. Consegui chegar até este ponto, mas até agora não consigo alinhá-los por cima:

```
<div style="width=40%">
     <a>
       <h:outputLabel value="Alta Prioridade" style="float: left;"/>
          <i style="margin-left: 50%; margin-right: 50%;" class="fa fa-thumb-tack" ></i>
       <h:outputLabel value="08/10/2015" style="float: right; text-align: right;"/>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

O código a seguir funciona em qualquer navegador. Se você quiser aumentar o tamanho da coluna central, diminua o tamanho de .col proporcionalmente, a soma das colunas nunca deve ultrapassar 100%

```css
i {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100px;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 29.999%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col.center {
  width: 40%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col left">Alta Prioridade</div>
  <div class="col center"><i></i></div>
  <div class="col right">08/10/2015</div>
</div>
```

Comment: O CSS para classe .left e .right não precisa?

Comment: Só se VC quiser valores diferentes pra coluna da esquerda e/ou direita